# Downsampling data in Matlab by averaging

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, data-manipulation, downsampling

I have 2 data sets in Matlab that I need to plot against one another - one on the xaxis and one on the yaxis. The data for each set was collected using a different method so the sampling rate is significantly different and until I don't the same number of data points in both sets I cannot plot one against the other.

Its quite simple to downsample data in Matlab using the `downsample` function Matlab.

```
A = [-3 -1.5 0 1.5 3 4.5 6 7.5 9...] (goes on until 21) 
B = [-3.9 -3.8 -3.7 -3.6 -3.5 -3.5 -3.3 -3.2 -3.1 -3.0 -2.9 -2.8...] (goes on until 22)
```

The sampling rate of A is 1.5s and the sampling rate of B is 0.1s. I have been able to successfully use `downsample` as `downsample(B,15,10)` to get it to start at the same time "-3s" (which means something in my data so I need to get it to start at that point) and be at the sample sampling rate of 1.5s.

Now, however, I was wondering whether there was a method which allowed me to take the average of the 15 points, instead of picking one point every 15 points? `downsample`, the way I have used it just picks every 15th point. I, however, would like for it to average the 15 points for me instead. Is there a way of doing this?

I wrote a for loop for a simple/smaller vector to see if I could do it. For `A = [1 2 3 4]` I would want to condense the data so that A only has 2 entries, such that it averages A(1) and A(2) and then A(3) and A(4).

```
A = [1 2 3 4] 
for i = 1:3
  P(i) = mean(A(i:i+1))
end
```

This, however, does not work like I want it to because I don't want it to average A(2) and A(3). I want it to take the first 2 entries, average them, then the next 2 entries, then average them. so on.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Ahh yes.. Sorry... I did try to look for existing answered questions I think my search words were different to the title though.

Comment: Yep, you explained quite detailed why you want to achieve, what you want to achieve. The possible duplicate wasn't even in the related topics, I just remembered it. Don't worry, still a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reshape your data `A` into an `n`-row matrix, where `n` is the averaging size, and apply `mean` to compute the average of each column:

```
A = [1 2 3 4]; %// data
n = 2; %// averaging size
P = mean(reshape(A,n,[]));
```